# mfc buttons will display incompletely if adding two buttons at runtime

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, user-interface, mfc

```
CButton *btn = new CButton();
btn->Create("btn", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(0,0,50,50), this, 1234);
btn = new CButton();
btn->Create("btn", WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(40,30,50,50), this, 1234);
```

running above code in CDialog::OnInitDialog() will only display first button correctly, the second button will be displayed incompletely.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CRect` constructor you're using is not doing what you think it's doing. The [4 parameter override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y3502k0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) takes left, right, top, bottom as parameters. You are simply making the rectangle too small - there's nothing incomplete about it.

As an aside you're giving both controls the same control ID of 1234 - that's potentially dangerous - you should rather give them unique values.